# 404 - File Not Found Controller or its method is not found: \App\Controllers\Ivy::codeignitor

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

I have a controller, named About:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

class About extends BaseController
{
     public function __construct()
    {
        
        $this->data['site_title'] = "About Us";
    }

    public function index()
    {
        //return view('welcome_message');
        return $this->_renderPage('About/index', $this->data);

    }
}
```

the render_page fucntion is in the basecontroller as follows:

```
 public function _renderPage($view, $data = [])
{
    $data = array_merge($this->data, $data);
    $data['_html_content'] = view('Home/' . $view, $data);
    return view('Home/page', $data);
}
```

My folder structure is:

1. app
2. ```
    -Controllers
   ```
3. ```
               - About
   ```
4. ```
               - Home
   ```
5. ```
               - Contact
   ```

My view files are as follows:

1. Views
2. ```
     -Home
   ```
3. ```
           -Contact
                    - index.php
   ```
4. ```
           -About
                    - index.php
   ```
5. ```
           - ...
   ```

The way I reference about is

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url('about') ?>">About</a>
```

My .htaccess file has this line of code:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f    
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d    
 RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Why do I still get the error: 404 - File Not Found
Controller or its method is not found: \App\Controllers\Ivy::codeignitor when I enter url:

```
localhost:8080/myproject/about
```

Comment: Did you add route to Routes.php ?

Comment: Yes. As, `$routes->add('about', 'About::index');`

Comment: Could you include your view files to make sure everything existed?

Comment: I have  made the edit and showed my folder structure for views

Answer (score 0):

try `<?= base_url()?>` instead `<?= site_url()?>`